# Rewrite files with certain extension to a specific directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

So... I have a few million PNGs with unique names spread across a complicated structure of directories that goes 15-20 levels deep, and I want to move them into a directory /my/special/directory/

I can't figure out a way to do this with rewrites (not redirects)

I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+).png?$ /my/special/directory/$1.png [R]
```

But this works on the first level only (root). I have also tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)([^/\.]+).png?$ /my/special/directory/$2.png [R]
```

But it doesn't work at all. How should I write this?

I am checking for the image not to exist because there are other directories in this vhost that contain images and will remain as they are.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand that pattern you try: `^([^/\.]+).png?$`...

Why the `?` at the end? And why the explicity denial of dots in file names? The reason this only works for "the first level" certainly is that you explicitly deny acceptance of paths with contained `/` which happens to be the folder delimiter...

Also just use `[L]` instead of `[R]` since you do not want a redirection.

This gives us:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.png$ /my/special/directory/$1.png [L]
```

In case you have to rewrite such that only the file name is captured (depends on the structure of your links, actually), this would probably be a good start:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /?([^/]+)\.png$ /my/special/directory/$1.png [L]
```

*Note: there is no leading `^` in the second variant, since you are not interested in what path is specified before the last folder separator...*

Comment: I tried that pattern as I was trying to get the file name into $1 - so what was after the last /. Sometimes the directory names contain dots. The 2nd rule you posted does work on all levels with R (redirects properly) but when rewriting (L) it does not - throws a 404.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with absolute versus relative paths to me... Can you post the base URL to the application?

Comment: It's OK I think I will leave it as a redirect, it won't be too much overhead, besides, I am using a CDN. Thank you for posting the very helpful answer!

Comment: Why that? This certainly can be solved. A redirect requires latency overhead, so it reduces the user experience. Not a nice thing.

Comment: Enable rewrite logging in your http servers host configuration, then monitor the rewrite log file for a single request. You will be shown exactly what is actually going on inside your rewriting engine step by step. Such issues _always_ can be solved. And you will learn a lot for future projects in the process of debugging and fixing. But a general remark: I do not understand how you want to use an internal rewriting with a CDN. Isn't that a contradiction in itself?

Comment: The browser hits my server first, the redirect kicks in and the browser will download the file from cloudfront. This is for backwards compatibility, since the applications that link to those images are already updated to use the CDN and new directory structure... but some search engines might have cached the old image paths and some users might have bookmarked them.  Thanks for the rewrite logging tip, was using apache for so long but didn't know it could do that.

Comment: Once more: it is impossible to do an internal rewrite to a CDN network resource. So to me it looks understandable that an external rewrite in your rewrite rule works, the internal one does not (since the resource is not available on your local system, but only under the CSN url).